# i cant update or install or add apps in kali linux

Tags: kali-linux

when i want to pdate or install some app whit the apt-get i have this error

```
> sudo apt-get update Hit:1 http://kali-za.bitcrack.net/kali
> kali-rolling InRelease Reading package lists... Done W: Skipping
> acquire of configured file 'contribdeb/binary-i386/Packages' as
> repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease' doesn't
> have the component 'contribdeb' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
> W: Skipping acquire of configured file
> 'contribdeb/i18n/Translation-en_US' as repository
> 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease' doesn't have the
> component 'contribdeb' (component misspelt in sources.list?) W:
> Skipping acquire of configured file 'contribdeb/i18n/Translation-en'
> as repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease'
> doesn't have the component 'contribdeb' (component misspelt in
> sources.list?) W: Skipping acquire of configured file
> 'contribdeb/dep11/Components-i386.yml' as repository
> 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease' doesn't have the
> component 'contribdeb' (component misspelt in sources.list?) W:
> Skipping acquire of configured file 'contribdeb/dep11/icons-64x64.tar'
> as repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease'
> doesn't have the component 'contribdeb' (component misspelt in
> sources.list?) W: Skipping acquire of configured file
> 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu/binary-i386/Packages'
> as repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease'
> doesn't have the component
> 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu'
> (component misspelt in sources.list?) W: Skipping acquire of
> configured file
> 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu/i18n/Translation-en_US'
> as repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease'
> doesn't have the component
> 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu'
> (component misspelt in sources.list?) W: Skipping acquire of
> configured file
> 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu/i18n/Translation-en'
> as repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease'
> doesn't have the component
> 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu'
> (component misspelt in sources.list?) W: Skipping acquire of
> configured file
> 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu/dep11/Components-i386.yml'
> as repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease'
> doesn't have the component
> 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu'
> (component misspelt in sources.list?) W: Skipping acquire of
> configured file
> 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu/dep11/icons-64x64.tar'
> as repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease'
> doesn't have the component
> 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu'
> (component misspelt in sources.list?) W: Skipping acquire of
> configured file 'lucid/binary-i386/Packages' as repository
> 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease' doesn't have the
> component 'lucid' (component misspelt in sources.list?) W: Skipping
> acquire of configured file 'lucid/i18n/Translation-en' as repository
> 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease' doesn't have the
> component 'lucid' (component misspelt in sources.list?) W: Skipping
> acquire of configured file 'lucid/i18n/Translation-en_US' as
> repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease' doesn't
> have the component 'lucid' (component misspelt in sources.list?) W:
> Skipping acquire of configured file 'lucid/dep11/Components-i386.yml'
> as repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease'
> doesn't have the component 'lucid' (component misspelt in
> sources.list?) W: Skipping acquire of configured file
> 'lucid/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali
> kali-rolling InRelease' doesn't have the component 'lucid' (component
> misspelt in sources.list?)
```

Comment: WOW! That really hurts! Please read about fomatting code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file (or one of the files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory) has typos.

First warning, lines re-wrapped for clarity and emphasis:

```
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 
'contribdeb/binary-i386/Packages' 
as repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease' 
doesn't have the component 'contribdeb' 
(component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

The word `contribdeb` is an important clue here.

The syntax of the `sources.list` files normally has `deb` as the first word on a non-comment line, and `contrib` is commonly (but not always) the last word on a line. `contribdeb` is a pretty sure sign of having two or more lines run together.